# Solving equation by Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, integral-equations

I have an equation and I have tried solving it to find values of b but it doesn't give me any values

The equation that I have tried to solve is :

```
ArcTan[1/d*Sqrt[(a+b)/(1-b)]]-(Vi/h)*Integrate[Sqrt[((1+(x/h)^2)^(-1))-b],{x,(h/2)*Log[b],0}]+(Pi/4)+m*Pi=0
```

I tried on it as following:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
int = Assuming[0 < b < 1,
  Integrate[Sqrt[((1 + (x/h)^2)^(-1))-b], {x, (h/2)*Log[b], 0}]]

(* -h ArcSinh[Log[b]/2] *)

a = 0; m = 0; c = 98/100; d = c - (a*(1 - c));

expr[Vi_, b_] = ArcTan[1/d*Sqrt[(a + b)/(1 - b)]] -
   (Vi/h)*int + (Pi/4) + m*Pi;
root[Vi_?NumericQ] := b /. 
 FindRoot[expr[Vi, b] == 0, {b, 0.3}]

viList = {4/5, 2, 4, 8};

Plot[Evaluate@
  Table[Tooltip[expr[Vi, b],
    StringForm["Vi = ``", Vi]], {Vi, viList}],
 {b, 0, 1},
 AxesLabel -> {b, HoldForm@expr[Vi, b]},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Tooltip[Point[pt = {root[#], 0}], pt[[1]]] & /@ viList},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   LineLegend[viList, LegendLabel -> Vi],
   {.7, .3}]][![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

but it does'nt give me solutions and give me an error as in the attachment

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

int = Assuming[{0 < b < 1, h > 0},
  Integrate[Sqrt[(1 + (x/h)^2)^(-1) - b], {x, (h/2)*Log[b], 0}] // 
   FullSimplify]

(* ConditionalExpression[
 I Sqrt[1 - b] h EllipticE[I ArcSinh[Log[b]/2], b/(-1 + b)], 
 2 Sqrt[-1 + 1/b] + Log[b] > 0] *)
```

The condition is equivalent to one of the assumptions and can be eliminated.

```
Reduce[int[[-1]], b, Reals]

(* 0 < b < 1 *)

int = int // Normal

(* I Sqrt[1 - b] h EllipticE[I ArcSinh[Log[b]/2], b/(-1 + b)] *)
```

Constants:

```
a = 0; m = 0; c = 98/100; d = c - (a*(1 - c));

expr[Vi_, b_] = 
  ArcTan[1/d*Sqrt[(a + b)/(1 - b)]] - (Vi/h)*int + (Pi/4) + m*Pi;

root[Vi_?NumericQ] := 
 NSolveValues[{expr[Vi, b] == 0, 0 < b < 1}, b][[1]]

viList = {0.8, 2, 4, 8};

Plot[Evaluate@
  Table[Tooltip[expr[Vi, b], StringForm["Vi = ``", Vi]], {Vi, viList}], {b, 0,
   1}, AxesLabel -> {b, HoldForm@expr[Vi, b]}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], 
   Tooltip[Point[pt = {root[#], 0}], pt[[1]]] & /@ viList}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[viList, LegendLabel -> Vi], {.7, .3}]]
```

[image]

```
step = 0.8; (*change to desired granularity*)

Grid[Prepend[Table[{Vi, root[Vi]}, {Vi, 0.8, 8, step}], {Vi, b}], 
 Frame -> All]
```

[image]